# Handle Swype and Copy Paste in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can I handle copy&paste action in Windows Phone? Another question is that how can I detect swype? I want to disable or filter it.

P.S. : they may be possible in 8.1 but I am talking about 8.0.

Comment: What swype you mean? The way you 'type' on keyboard or flick gestures when you swipe from left to right or vice versa on your screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle copy/paste via `Clipboard` class. [Here is MSDN reference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.105).aspx).
If I recall correctly you need to have Silverlight app to access this `Clipboard` class.